# PHP: how to get the host for an ajax request?

Tags: php, ajax, hostname

I have an API server, and I want to implement public an private api keys. The idea behind public API keys is to use them in javascript applications ajax calls from web browsers. In order to fully validate that the key I want to make sure the domain name it is coming from  is in a list of trusted domains.

how would I get the host name for this kind of call?

Answer (score 1):

Your API server would check `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. That'll get you the client's IP. If you're doing hostname-based filtering, you'd have to do a reverse DNS lookup to map that IP back to a hostname (e.g. [`gethostbyaddr()`](http://php.net/gethostbyaddr)), though not all IPs have reverse mappings defined.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would this work for ajax calls? I was using gethostbyaddr, but wouldn't $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] be the IP of the client (the user not the server)? the php doc says about the REMOTE_ADDR "The IP address from which the user is viewing the current page." http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php . Then I will get the IP for the user and will not get a valid domain in return, even if I validate against the IP addresses I wouldn't have a valid IP. I'm I right? or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: ajax calls are just regular http calls done in the background in the browser. there's no server-side difference between an ajax call and a regular "click on a link" or "submit a form" request. You'd still get the IP of the user's machine or the nat gateway  they're going through (e.g. their home dsl/cable modem/router).